# php- preg_match not working nor str_replace

Tags: php, regex, str-replace

`str_replace` and `preg_match` are not working in following code.

```
$url = 'http://www.ima-appweb.com/hub/emailers/2017-07/website-emailer-2/';

$opts = array('http'=>array('header' => "User-Agent:MyAgent/1.0\r\n")); 
//Basically adding headers to the request
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$html = file_get_contents($url,false,$context,0,2700);
$html = htmlspecialchars($html);
echo $html;

if(preg_match_all('#<td colspan="3"> Corp off: I – 128, 2nd Floor, Mohammadpur, Bikaji, New Delhi 110066. <br> © Copyright 2014 by Ima Appweb. All Rights Reserved. </td>#', $html)){
    $outputs = str_replace('<td colspan="3"> Corp off: I – 128, 2nd Floor, Mohammadpur, Bikaji, New Delhi 110066. <br> © Copyright 2014 by Ima Appweb. All Rights Reserved. </td>','<td colspan="3"><strong> Address: '.$address.', '.$city.', '.$country.'<br/>'.$website.'<br/>© Copyright By sunny '.$company.'</strong></td>',$html);
} else {
    echo 'didnot match';
}
```

Comment: Of course they cannot find the string in the text of the page. The text is there but it contains some newlines that are not present in your string.

Answer (score 0):

You miss newlines and spaces in html code. Look at it

```
                <td colspan="3">
                   Corp off: I – 128, 2nd Floor, Mohammadpur, Bikaji, New Delhi 110066. 
<br>
© Copyright 2014 by Ima Appweb. All Rights Reserved.
                      </td>
```

Each line break have newline symbols. There are a lot od spaces before `<td>`